# Explode column into columns

Tags: python, pandas

I got pandas train df which looks like this:

```
                 image
1  [[0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1]]
2  [[1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 1]]
2  [[0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1]]
```

Is there any way to "explode" it but into columns

```
   1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
1  0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1
2  1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1
2  0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1
```

Comment: Not quite straightforward from the dup link since OP has list of list in each cell. Here's a one-liner that works in this case `pd.DataFrame(df.image.apply(np.concatenate).values.tolist())`

Comment: You could use `itertools` : ``from itertools import chain; 
 pd.DataFrame(chain.from_iterable(entry) for entry in df.image)``

Comment: Reopened @QuangHoang

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`np.vstack` the Series of lists of lists, then `reshape`

```
pd.DataFrame(np.vstack(df['image']).reshape(len(df), -1))

   0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8
0  0  0  0  1  0  1  0  1  1
1  1  1  1  0  0  1  0  0  1
2  0  0  1  0  1  1  1  1  1
```